# How to name a Document with Docu Sign API tool kit

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Apex Toolkit to create a Signer Document. It all works good but when Document is attached to Salesforce files, Document File name is set as 'Name.pdf'. I want to rename the Document. How can I set the Document name from Apex Toolkit? IS there a way I can pass custom page name using APEX DocuSign Toolkit

```html
Id mySourceId; // The ID of the initiating Salesforce object.

// Create an empty envelope.
dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
    new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));
 // The initiating Salesforce entity.

//Use myEnvelope for later
//we will use a Salesforce contact record as a Recipient here
Contact myContact = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

//use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
            myContact.Name, // Recipient name
            myContact.Email, // Recipient email
            null, //Optional phone number
            'Signer 1', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
            new dfsle.Entity(myContact.Id)); //source object for the Recipient

//add Recipient to the Envelope
myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myRecipient });
//myTemplateId contains the DocuSign Id of the DocuSign Template
dfsle.UUID myTemplateId = dfsle.UUID.parse('01234567-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-456789abcdef');

//create a new document for the Envelope
dfsle.Document myDocument = dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(
    myTemplateId, // templateId in dfsle.UUID format
    'myTemplate'); // name of the template

//add document to the Envelope
myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> { myDocument });
// Send the envelope.
myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
    myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
    true); // Send now?
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apex Toolkit does not use file names it uses file id.
Looking at the above and testing it in my sandbox suggests that the template name or your code may be the issue.